# Backsolving power curve with uplift

Tags: calculus, summation, exponential-function

We have a curve $cx ^ b$.
Let's say I sum $x$ 1 through to 52 using that curve and it gives me a number, say 10.
I want to increase number 10 by 10% and we know that's 11.
I can increase 10% very easily by just multiplying by 1.1.
What I want to solve is what I can change in the equation $c* x ^ b$ to make it equal 11
But I only want to change something to do with $b$.

We can assume $x$ can always be limited between 1 to 52

Can someone help me solve this? I would like this solved in the most laymen's terms

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a nice form for $s=c\sum_{x=1}^{52}x^b$ for $b$ not an integer.  There is a nice form for $b$ integer.  You need to use a one dimensional root finder.  The nice thing is that you have an easy derivative:  $\frac {ds}{db}=s \log b$

In your example, the first order approximation is $\Delta b=\dfrac {\Delta s}{\frac {ds}{db}}=\frac 1{10 \log b}$

Comment: Thankyou, I forgot to mention. b is negative

Comment: It doesn't matter.  I could tell that it was, because if it is positive the sum would be greater than $52$.  For  $c=1$ (you can absorb $c$ into the desired sum) [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve+sum%28i%5Ex%29+%7Bi%2C1%2C52%7D%3D10) gives $b \approx -0.61$